# File downloading failing in Android Marshmallow and Lollipop

Tags: java, android

I have created a 'MP4 File Download' Button. It's working fine in android Android Pie and Oreo but not working in Marshmallow or Lollipop. It doesn't download the file in those versions. Can someone point out what I am missing in my code? Thanks in advance.

Here is my download code

```
public class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private String fileName;
    private String folder;
    private boolean isDownloaded;

    /**
     * Before starting background thread
     * Show Progress Bar Dialog
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        this.progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        this.progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        this.progressDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            // getting file length
            int lengthOfFile = connection.getContentLength();


            // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss").format(new Date());

            //Extract file name from URL
            fileName = f_url[0].substring(f_url[0].lastIndexOf('/') + 1, f_url[0].length());

            //Append timestamp to file name
            fileName = timestamp + "_" + fileName;

            //External directory path to save file
            folder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Bharti News/";

            //Create androiddeft folder if it does not exist
            File directory = new File(folder);

            if (!directory.exists()) {
                directory.mkdirs();
            }

            // Output stream to write file
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(folder + fileName);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lengthOfFile));
                Log.d(TAG, "Progress: " + (int) ((total * 100) / lengthOfFile));

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();
            return "Downloaded at: " + folder + fileName;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return "Something went wrong";
    }

    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage
        progressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
        // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
        this.progressDialog.dismiss();

        // Display File path after downloading
        Toast.makeText(context,
                message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

And this is how I am calling it.

```
new DownloadFile().execute(item.getBodyurl());
```

It gives me this error - '/storage/emulated/0/Bharti News/2019-05-22-02-19-09_dWJZ7AQesz48Ol2o.mp4: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be checking if the user has granted permission of external storage by using:

```
if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
    new DownloadFile().execute(item.getBodyurl());
    return true;
}else{ ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE);}
```